# Angularjs to spring controller

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I am fairly new to angularjs. Now I have a checkbox in one of my views

```
<input id="{{fields[3].name}}" type="checkbox" value="{{fields[3].name}}" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(fields[3].name) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(fields[3].name)" class="col-xs-1" />
```

In spring controller(like below) how do I check if the checkbox was checked?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{id}/accept", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
        public @ResponseBody ResponseBean acceptData(
                @PathVariable("id") String id,
                @RequestBody AcceptPayload payload, Model model,
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
....
    }
```

Any code examples will help

Comment: add ng-model in that and throught http call you can send check-box info.

Comment: When do you want to check that ? After submiting ? On the client side ? In real time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to send the checked data from your webpage to the controller.

The web page will have ng-repeat as below. The variable list contains the json array:

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in list"> 
    <td> 
           <input id="{{obj.name}}" type="checkbox" value="{{obj.name}}" 
           checklist-model="checkboxes" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(obj.name) > -1" 
           ng-click="toggleSelection(obj.name)" />
   </td>
</tr>
```

The **toggleSelection()** function will get the array of selected **obj.name** and add it to variable array **selectedItems **:

```
$scope.selectedItems = [];
$scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(name) {
    var idx = $scope.selectedItems.indexOf(name);
    // is currently selected
    if (idx > -1) {
        $scope.selectedItems.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    // is newly selected
    else {
        $scope.selectedItems.push(name);
    }
};
```

The way in which I would hit the controller in the webpage would be below:

```
$scope.execute = function() {
    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : 'trigger',
        params : {
                     selectedItems : $scope.selectedItems
                }
        }).success(
            function(data, status, headers, config) {
        }).error(
            function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
                        };
```

The method in controller would look like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/trigger", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody String trigger(@RequestParam("selectedItems") List<String> selectedItems) throws NumberFormatException, Exception {
        // Your method
    }
```

You can change the method from GET to POST as you would want it.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is a front end MVC library. The spring controller is back-end. This means that the value has to be sent from the front to the back over an HTTP request.

For example, in HTML,

```
ng-checked="someVariable"
```

can be captured in the angular app controller within the scope with

```
$scope.someVariable
```

This value has then to be sent over network to your Spring controller through HTTP request. Something like,

```
$http({  method: 'POST',  data: 'someVariable'  url: '/someUrl'})
.then(function successCallback(response) {
// this callback will be called asynchronously
// when the response is available
}, function errorCallback(response) {
// called asynchronously if an error occurs
// or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

Please refer to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http